# How do I recreate this header formatting in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

question is as the title says. How do I recreate the formatting in this header? More specifically how do I have the text that follows the colons to be vertically in line with each other regardless of how far the text that preceded the colons reached. Also what is this spacing method called?

Here is the screenshot of the text:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please tell us what you have tried or researched? Did you try using tabs? Or a table table? What were the results? We can help you resolve it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming Charlie. I hadn't tried using tables or tabs, but after looking up tabs they have suited my needs perfectly. My biggest problem was with terminology, I wasn't sure how to search for the right answer. I knew you guys would be able to help, thank you.

Comment: Great. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears tab stops are being used align the text.

Alternately, a border-less table can be used to align text.